# Autowiring error message at automatic server restart in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, intellij-idea, spring-boot, lombok, intellij-lombok-plugin

This is my setup

- IntelliJ IDEA
- Spring Boot with Devtools
- Lombok

Everything works fine but about every second automatic server restart I get the following error message:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field billingCode in com.whatever.model.BillingCodeRowMapper required a bean of type 'com.whatever.model.BillingCode' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.whatever.model.BillingCode' in your configuration.
```

My `main` looks like this:

```
package com.whatever;    

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

My `BillingCode` class looks like this:

```
package com.whatever.model;

import lombok.Data;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.Date;

@Component
@Data
public class BillingCode {

    private int billingCodeId;
    private String billingCodeName;
    private Boolean billingCodeFuelSurcharge;
    private Boolean billingCodeToll;
    private String billingCodeAccount;
    private float billingCodeVat;
    private Date billingCodeDateAdded;
    private Date billingCodeDateChanged;
    private Boolean billingCodeShippingSurcharge;
    private Boolean billingCodeCurrencySurcharge;
    private String billingCodeMarking;

}
```

`BillingCode` is `@Autowired`  in `BillingCodeRowMapper` and if I stop the server and start it manually it all works fine. Is the autowiring being loaded in different order sometimes or is it an IJ issue or is it an issue with Lombok?

Comment: Can I see your BillingCode class?

Comment: @JoséMendes sure, added to the original post

Comment: I see you marked as `@Component` correctly but check if this is on a `SubPacakge` of your main class. For example, if your main class is at `com.something` your class should be in a package like `com.something.somepackage`

Comment: Post for me your `Main Class`, where your `@SpringbootApplication` is being used please.

Comment: @JoséMendes added `main`

Comment: It looks normal for me, the only thing I could suggest is try to remove the '@Data' just to see if this is causing the issue, the rest is correct. If it does not solve try to clean the `target` folder before running again.

Comment: @JoséMendes removing `@Data` (I guess that disables Lombok) and adding regular getters and setters seems to have solved the issue.

Comment: Can you show the full stacktrace of your application when it crashes?